# Using Crashlytics without plugin via cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics

Is it possible to use crashlytics and [fabric](https://fabric.io) without installing the mac plugin for iOS?

I found this [fabric pod](https://github.com/zergtmn/Fabric) that allows you to get the necessary frameworks for fabric to work, but when I build my app, I'm getting this message:

```
Fabric: This app relies on Fabric. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install Fabric.app then ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

If this machine is a build server please remove Fabric.app if present and use xcodebuild so that SchoolSpring.app.dSYM is uploaded.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fabric now supports installation with CocoaPods: http://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/cocoapods.html

If you are just looking for `Crashlytics` you can use these two pods:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Along with adding the following build phase script:

```
${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run
```

[image: Run Script Build Phase]

Comment: Wow so this means I can use the standard cocoapods procedures to install it? no add-ons needed? Me happy!

Answer (score 1):

There is an official pod spec now from Twitter: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/Fabric

Comment: Is that pod spec official? It looks like it was put together by an independent developer. Reading through the 'Issues' it also looks like it is a few versions behind the current.

Comment: Just as a heads up. That link *now* points to the official Spec from Twitter. Before last week it had been a third-party Spec that pointed to the frameworks publicly available online (but unsupported distributed through CocoaPods).